# Current taxonomy item in custom taxonomy term page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I've got a custom taxonomy called `trailer_type` with terms `long` and `short`. When visiting `my_site/trailers/short` (a page powered by template `taxonomy-trailer_type.php`) I display my taxonomy terms this way:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'trailer_type' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Works well but is there a simple way to add a "current" class? For example if I'm on the "long" page, I'd need "long" to have "current" class in this menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at the queried object. There's several ways to do it, here's what I tend to use: `$wp_query->queried_object` - this returns, as the name implies, the queried object.

In your case, something like this should work:

```
$curTerm =  $wp_query->queried_object;
$terms = get_terms( 'trailer_type' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $classes = array();
        if ($term->name == $curTerm->name)
            $classes[] = 'current';
        echo '<li class="'. implode(' ',$classes) .'"><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

I'm setting the classes to an array simply for future expansion. You could set it to a string right away as well.

Comment: Thanks, but a var_dump() of $wp_query->queried_object returns nothing on term page (my_site/trailers/short/), only on archive page (my_site/trailers/). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @drake035 something broke your main query, and I can almost definitely say you are using `query_posts` somewhere or you have a plugin using `query_posts`. `$wp_query->queried_object` cannot return nothing on a taxonomy page unless the main query is broken via `query_posts`

Comment: @drake035 for testing to ensure this code works, perhaps try moving the above code (or your `var_dump`) to the top of the template file, right below `get_header()`. @pieter is I think on the right track here, it's probably a `query_posts` or other alteration to the Loop issue. Moving this to the top will make it display before most of these alterations tend to occur. If it does work, you know the issue is between there and where you had it originally. If it still doesn't, the issue is in the header somewhere (unlikely).

Comment: Please disregard my silliness, I had only pasted your code on archive page. Your solution works 100%, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
get_query_var( 'term' )
```

and check

```
if ($term->name == get_query_var( 'term' )){
//make something
}
```